# avoid executing the same method in all scala actions in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a trait which each controller inherits from. The requirement is to check the url in all the actions defined in the controller. I find it is pretty annoying to execute this method in each controller. Is there a way to execute this method in just one place?

Trait

```
trait Validator extends Controller {
    def checkurl(implicit request:RequestHeader)={
        //code to check url
  }
}
```

Controller

```
object UserHandler extends Controller with Validator{
   def showuser = Action {
       implicit request =>
          checkurl(request)
          Ok("...")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a helper `def`:

```
trait Validator extends Controller {
  def checkurl(implicit request: RequestHeader)={
     //code to check url
  }

  def checkedAction(block: Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContext] =
    Action { implicit request =>
      checkUrl
      block(request)
    }
}

object UserHandler extends Controller with Validator {
  def showuser = checkedAction { implicit request =>
    Ok("...")
  }
}
```

Comment: how about my action is a securesocial securedaction? Can i have 2 helpers at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `GlobalSettings` and override `onRequest` method. It is an interceptor for all the requests made to your app.

Comment: since Validator is a trait,how can i execute its checkurl method in that onRequest method?

Comment: Why would you want to encapsulate checkUrl logic to trait? Check this link: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal